# How to access elements of set of maps? C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, set

I have a set of maps `set<map<string, string>> synonyms` and my task is to check each string(in other words, access key and value of each element in the set). So I did the following:

```
for (const auto& s : synonyms) {
    if (s.first == word || s.second == word) {
        ++amount;
    }
}
```

(where I iterate `amount` if `word` was found in an element). However, the compiler says that the map `has no member named first` (and `second`). What is the problem? How do I correctly access the set elements?

Comment: You did correctly access the set elements: `s` is a `map<string, string>`, an element of the set. You probably need a nested loop to access that map's elements.

Comment: Consider this: does `std::map<std::string,std::string>` have members `first` and `second` ? And frankly, I highly question your architecture. If anything a db of synonyms would utilize a `std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>>`, and if you think about you'll see why.

Comment: I agree with the other comments questioning the use of a `std::set<std::map>>` for this purpose, though my first choice would probably be an `std::multimap<std::string, std::string>` or an `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>`. I think a `vector` is preferable to `set` for the values mostly because the list of synonyms rarely changes, and you're more likely to list all of them than check to see whether a particular word is present.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, I have changed the type to `map<string, set<string>>`, it is now easier to work with the code. However, I still have the compilation error same as mentioned in the question above  (for ex, when I used `synonyms[key].second.size()` to access a specific `key`'s set).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why std::map is necessary, but this should do what you want.

```
for (const auto& s : synonyms) {
    auto object = s.begin();
    if (object->first == word || object->second == word) {
        ++amount;
    }
}
```

Since each element in your set `s` is a map of size 1, you can access its element by using an iterator on its beginning.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (const std::map<string, string>& m : synonyms)
    {
      for (const std::pair<string, string>& p : m)
      {
        if (p->first == word || p->second == word)
        {
          ++amount;
        }
      }
    }
```